# UWP, loading windows runtime component == Requested Windows Runtime type "..." is not registreated

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I like to create platform independent apps for Win/Mac/Linux, Android and so on but the platform I have most problems with (except iOS) is UWP...

So now I want to load a external project, a Window Runtime Component-dll, when I have the component as a project in the same solution in visual studio it works fine.

When I build the component outside visual studio and referencing it to
my project I get this error when I call a class stored in the runtime component:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Requested Windows Runtime type
>   '**SharpDepend_UWP_DirectXInterop.D3DPanel**' is not registered.' Inner
>   Exception COMException: Klassen har inte registrerats (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I have these projects:

1. My project **(UWP app, C#)**
2. SharpDepend_UWP **(PCL, C#)**
3. SharpDepend_UWP.DirectXInterop **(Windows runtime component, C++)**

And the SharpDepend projets is my external dlls, and they are stored in a Binaries-folder with all output generated files, dll and winmd.

Everything compiles but I get the error when the first class in loading in the DirectXInterop projects.

Is there anyone who is expert in UWP and know the problem? :)

Comment: It means that the OS could not find the component back in the AppX manifest.  It has never been clear to me how programmers exactly build their programs wrong to get this problem.  "build the component outside" probably has something to do with it.  Just google "Requested Windows Runtime type is not registered" to learn more, lots of hits.

Comment: Haha, thanks
"stackoverflow.com/a/20637241/17034 – Hans Passant Aug 30 '16 at 8:07"

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the component DLL and Winmd files **did not** had the same name.
My component was named with a '.' char and when Visual Studio compile the Winmd replaces the '.' to an '_' but didnt do that for the DLL file.

Note:
After that I also had to manually copy some files from the component project to my App-project:
SimplePixelShader.cso and SimpleVertexShader.cso.
Otherwise my app didnt found them and they seems to not be baked in the dll or winmd file.